# LibGDX TextButton removes numbers from string

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have been having a unique problem with the LibGDX TextButton. In some cases, when setting the text of the button, the string lacks numbers (even though they are present in the string which can be seen in the output). Here is an example:

[image]

The string should be dates, e.g. January 8th, 1997.
Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Edit:
Code for adding the buttons

```
TextButton button = new TextButton("", skin) //initialized as empty until API call is done
button.setText(text); //set after API call is finalized by first retrieving from stage root by name (stage.getRoot().find("button");
```

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to create one of these buttons, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: This is likely a problem with your bitmap font, like missing characters.